# background image failing me with simple css

Tags: html, css

I'm sure there is a ridiculously simple answer for why this simple example is not showing my the background image but I just don't see it.  I'm expecting to see the image twice, once when the image uses the class, and once when it references the image directly.

Thoughts

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style>
            .chkCombo {
                background: transparent url(http://cache.siliconvalley-codecamp.com/Images/silicon-valley-code-camp.png);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div class="x">
           <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="chkCombo">
        </div>
         <hr />
            <div class="x">
           <img  src="http://cache.siliconvalley-codecamp.com/Images/silicon-valley-code-camp.png" />
       </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: How big is the `base64` image and what is it an image of? If you set background image of an `img` tag using CSS, the actual `img` will overlay on top of the CSS background.

Comment: the image is just simple small public image.  I'm expecting to see 2 images and I only see one.  the base64 image is right there. it's just a 1x1 invisible gif.  try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding height and width to the image and setting it to `display: block;` the image will appear.

Here is a the fixed [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4WksE/)

By the way, I don't see the effect of the base64 image, you use it and also using a class with background image on the same element.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure why I have the base64 image.  It's from an ExtJS example that I am working with.  I thought it had something to do with taking up the space before the class is applied but I'm not sure.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work as you can see. The base64 code seems too short honestly.
In case you have no use of the image as base64 you can simply drop it.

Answer (score 0):

**Try using this style**

```
.chkCombo {
    height: 56px;
    width: 350px;
    background: transparent url(http://cache.siliconvalley-codecamp.com/Images/silicon-valley-code-camp.png);
}
```

**A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yb4Lr/) demo**

P.S: A background image is litteraly a "**background**" image so if an element has no dimentions(height and width) then the background image will have no dimentions. Therefore you need to give it a hight and width